# Verificar tipo de dato de parametro para luego iterar JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código en el que de acuerdo al tipo de dato pasado al parametro deberia darle valor a argumentos para luego poder iterar sobre el.

Con el `array` funciona perfecto y me devuelve el total.
Pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar con el `string`, ¿que es lo que estaria haciendo mal?.

Yo quiero que la funcion verifique si el parametro a es un `string`, y si lo es, pasarlo a array con el metodo split y luego poder iterar sobre el.

```js
var ry = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var str = "1, 2, 3, 4";

function total2(a) {
  var total = 0;
  var argumentos;

  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    argumentos = a;
  } else if (typeof a === "string") {
    argumentos = a.split(",");
  } else {
    argumentos = arguments;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < argumentos.length; i++) {
    total += argumentos[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(total2(ry)); // 15 CORRECTO
console.log(total2(str)); //  "01, 2, 3, 4"
console.log(total2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer `split(',')` obtenes un arreglo de `strings`.
Para poder sumarlos, tenes que convertilos a `number`.

#### Solución:

Podes usar [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) y [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

##### Ejemplo:

```js
var ry = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var str = "1, 2, 3, 4";

function total2(a) {
  var total = 0;
  var argumentos;

  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    argumentos = a;
  } else if (typeof a === "string") {
    argumentos = a.split(",").map(n => parseInt(n));
  } else {
    argumentos = arguments;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < argumentos.length; i++) {
    total += argumentos[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(total2(ry)); // 15 CORRECTO
console.log(total2(str)); //  "01, 2, 3, 4"
console.log(total2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); // 15
```

Comment: Claro pero que ingenuo, estaba dando vueltas y no me di cuenta de eso, tambien podria ser con Number(), muchas gracias siempre esta comunidad ayudando a entender. Te agradezco

Comment: Hecho, muchas gracias.